# In French, how to say "a face guy"?

Tags: expressions, anglais

> Excuse me for being more of **a 'face' guy**, but I was drawn to her ocean-blue eyes and angelic face the moment I set my eyes on her.

"A face guy" is a rather derogatory term used to describe a shallow man who, setting great store by physical attractiveness, only shows interest in the looks of his potential date. Her personality and whatnot only come a distant second.

Incidentally, in Japanese  we have a commonly used slang-ish word, 面食い, that means more or less the same thing.

I wonder if French has an equivalent expression?

Comment: Incidentally, you can be an anything guy, I think.

Answer (score 3):

You can say "un homme attaché aux apparences", which means that the guy gives a lot of importance to the exterior aspects of people, to their appearances.
It has a negative connotation.

Answer (score 2):

> Il est porté sur le physique.

Or

> Il attache plus d'importance au physique.

But it does not have the same negative connotation as *face guy*.

Answer (score 1):

I would translate it as "un homme superficiel", which pretty much describes the idea of a "face" guy: a man only looking into the physical characteristics of his potential date.

Comment: *Superficiel* does not really convey the idea that the guy is only interested in the physical characteritics; people can be *superficiel* in so many other ways, such as being interested only in money, in having fun, etc.

Comment: @Greg That's true it also means that, but I heard and read *superficiel* being used quite some times to describe this. I guess it also depends on the context when it is used.